# Scala list of list count different elements per sublist index

Tags: list, scala

I have a list of lists with the following data

> val list = List(List("a","b","c"),List("d","e","f"),List("a","a","a"))

I want to disicover how many different data do I have in each position of the sublists

> 1 -> List("a","d","a")
>
> 2 -> List("b","e","a")
>
> 3 -> List("c","f","a")

Is there a way to do that? It doesn't need to be indexed, but I need the amount of different values per sublist index, the result could also be

> 2 // different values a and d
>
> 3 // different values b, e and a
>
> 3 // different values c, f and a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noted in a comment on Jhonny Everson's (almost right but now deleted) answer, you can use `transpose` to get a list of the columns, and then `distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
scala> list.transpose.map(_.distinct.size)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 3)
```

This will throw an exception if all the lists don't have the same size, but that's probably what you want.

Comment: Best answer. Why was it downvoted? And why isn't it accepted?

Comment: @JeanLogeart I wasn't online until now

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> list.transpose.map(_.toSet.size)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 3)
```

The output of `list.transpose` is `List(List(a, d, a), List(b, e, a), List(c, f, a))` which gives you the structure you want then map each `List` to a `Set` to get the unique elements and count them.

If you want unique elements per position, then you can use `zipWithIndex` and reverse the outputs.

```
scala> list.transpose.map(_.distinct).zipWithIndex.map(t => t._2 -> t._1)
res1: List[(Int, List[String])] = List((0,List(a, d)), (1,List(b, e, a)), (2,List(c, f,   a)))
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer when it was a single line of code with no context that more or less duplicated the conversation in comments on Jhonny Everson's answer. I still think using `toSet` isn't a very good solution (even if it's not exactly wrong): why use a conversion to another kind of collection when `distinct` captures the intent more clearly?

Comment: @TravisBrown Isn't toSet more efficient then distinct? Distinct preserves the order of the elements, which in this case isn't needed. I agree that the distinct method make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code you wanted:

```
var lOfl = List(List.range(1,5), List(2,2,2,3), Nil)
   //> lOfl  : List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(2, 2, 2, 3), List())
for {
   l <- lOfl
} yield l.toSet.count(_ => true)  //> res1: List[Int] = List(4, 2, 0)
```

A sample list of list of Int is created as lOfl; for loop iterates through each list of Int; toSet converts list to set eliminating duplicate elements. then count function does as the name says it all.
 OR use the Scala's most used collection function (:P :P), map, like below,

```
  lOfl.map(l => l.toSet.count(_ => true) )       //> res2: List[Int] = List(4, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted your question, in fact I appreciate all efforts to help.

Comment: In fact this isn't what I am trying to do. I want to count the number of times that each element appear per index. In your case, considering changing the code to List.range(1,4) the wanted result should be. List(1,2,1,1) as the lists are (1,2,3,4) and (2,2,2,3), in this case the only repeating element is 2 in the second column. Wasn't that clear in the question? If not I can update it.

Comment: Yes, I was lil confused with your question. Anyway you got a correct answer.

Comment: I've updated it for clarification, take a look and tell me if it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes it is clear now. And the answer I gave does what you expected except that it does on List[List[Int]] instead of List[List[String]]. You modify the input like below and check. var lOfl = List(List("a","b","a"), List("c"),...)..

Comment: In fact your code is counting the number of distinct elements in each list. What I want is to count the number of the distinct elements in each position of each list. If we have 3 lists of 4 elements, I wan't to count the distinct elements at position 0, 1, 2 and 3, ok?